# Is it possible to setup a WebRTC Twilio client on Raspberry PI?

Tags: twilio, raspberry-pi2

I'm working on a prototype on which I need to create a peer-to-peer video chat between a Raspberry Pi equipped with a Raspberry Cam and an iOS device using Twilio. The iOS part was easy but I can't find a way to do the same on the Raspberry. Is that even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried this, but it seems like you would have to rely on the browser capabilities of the Pi. The current standard there seems to be the Epiphany browser which you'd get with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install epiphany-browser
```

Then you can check whether that browser would support using Twilio Client:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client

Alternatively, if for whatever reason it would not work with Twilio Client, you could still use the Pi as a WebRTC device via other methods as modeled in [this blog post](http://www.rs-online.com/designspark/electronics/blog/building-a-raspberry-pi-2-webrtc-camera).

I don't have a Raspberry Pi 2 or camera to test this with so let me know if this helps at all.